# Storing coredata array through prepareForSegue in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray

I need to pass an array of CoreData entities from my main view to a TableViewController.

I used a lot of stackoverflow posts to help myself with that, and thought it worked.

But when I build my app, I have a thread problem, displaying:

`[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".`

I did some checks and the problem is, in my tableView, the number of Row is set to 0.

So here is my code :

My prepareForSegue function in my MainViewController.m:

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sgPushDetail"])
    {
        checkDataSavedTableViewController *detail = segue.destinationViewController;
        detail.datasToDisplay = _listOfDatas;
    }
}
```

- listOfDatas is an NSArray of NSManagedObject, declared in my
  MainViewController.h
- datasToDisplay is an NSArray declared in my TableViewController.

Here is my function to put my datas in the TableViewController:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dataCells" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *rowArray = self.datasToDisplay[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = rowArray;
    return cell;
}
```

(But the error appears in the ViewDidLoad so meeeh)

How can I proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I AM STUPID.

Since I use CoreData, I already have a list of my entities. I don't need my NSArray of randomMeh, I just need that:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Answer (score 0):

put break point in `prepareforsegue`. And check your array. I think your array is nil so that your table view is not getting data. Put neccessary breakpoints or you can prints array in `prepareforsegue` and in `viewdidload` of tableviewcontroller and check you are getting data in array!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I already did that, and I know that my array is nul. But the problem is, i found it on stackoverflow, and it worked for everybody else xD

Comment: Then find reason why your array is null. check your data base. check hows you fetching data from database. it is not problem of prepareforsegue or tableview

Comment: I just add the nil value at the end of my array, and right now i don't have the error anymore. But i only store the first attribute of the last entity i added. Newbie on objective C, i'll continue to roam stackoverflow to find something ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in  `NSString *rowArray = self.datasToDisplay[indexPath.row];`

**datasToDisplay** is an Array of NsManagedObject not an array of Strings. So you need to get string value from your NsManagedObject :

```
NSString *rowArray = [self.datasToDisplay[indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"stringKey"]
```

Comment: Between my question and right now, i just change that line:

_listOfDatas = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[newContact valueForKey:@"name"], nil];

(I placed the nil value). Right now i don't have the error anymore, but my array only store the first attribute of the last entity I saved.

I think the problem is truly somewhere else.
I would love to have the += operator for my array right now ^^ 

In your answer, what does the valueForKey equals to? The array value? Entity value?